# BeautifulSoup Python NoneType object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a javascript loaded website [https://e-consulta.sunat.gob.pe/cl-at-ittipcam/tcS01Alias](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE6JS.png) by using selenium and beautifulsoup 4.

However, when trying to retrieve an element or subitem (a sub-branch) from the tree, i get this error

```
bloquefecha=bloque.find('div[@class="date"]').text
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

[i'm attaching HERE a snapshot of my code and the developers console for illustrative purposes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE6JS.png)

Here is my code:

```
def beautifulseleniumsunat2():
navegador = webdriver.Chrome()
navegador.get("https://e-consulta.sunat.gob.pe/cl-at-ittipcam/tcS01Alias")
time.sleep(7)  # esperamos 7 segundos a que cargue la pagina
pagsunat = navegador.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(pagsunat, "html.parser")
print (soup.prettify())

bloquesdias2 = soup.select('td[class*="table-bordered calendar-day current"]')
listafecha = []
listacompra=[]
listaventa=[]
for bloque in bloquesdias2:
    bloquefecha=bloque.find('div[@class="date"]') #ALSO tried with findall and iterating with FOR loop on each element but ERROR says it's not iterable
    listafecha.append(bloquefecha.text)
    bloquecompra=bloque.find('div[@class="event normal-all-day begin end"]') #ALSO tried with findall and iterating with FOR loop on each element but ERROR says it's not iterable
    listacompra.append(bloquecompra.text)
    bloqueventa = bloque.find('div[@class="event pap-all-day begin end"]') #ALSO tried with findall and iterating with FOR loop on each element but ERROR says it's not iterable
    listaventa.append(bloquecompra.text)

listafinal=[listacompra,listaventa,listafecha]
print (listafinal)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What happens?

As mentioned by *Aziz Sonawalla* you have to pass the class as separat argument to `find()` but that wont fix all your issues. Cause if elements not available it will raise an error again e.g. if there is no compra / ventra entry.

### How to fix that ?

You have to fetch the error - `try` will give you the result if there is no error `except` will set result to empty string.

```
try:
        bloquecompra = day.select_one('div[class*="normal-all-day"]').get_text().split()[1]
    except:
        bloquecompra = ''
```

**Example**

You can replace all your code after print `(soup.prettify())`:

```
data = []

for day in soup.select('table.calendar-table.table.table-condensed > tbody td[class*="current"]'):
    bloquefecha = day.select_one('div.date').get_text()
    try:
        bloquecompra = day.select_one('div[class*="normal-all-day"]').get_text().split()[1]
    except:
        bloquecompra = ''
    
    try:
        bloqueventa = day.select_one('div[class*="pap-all-day"]').get_text().split()[1]
    except:
        bloqueventa = ''
    
    data.append(';'.join([bloquefecha,bloquecompra,bloqueventa]))
data
```

**Output**

```
['1;3.618;3.624',
 '2;;',
 '3;;',
 '4;;',
 '5;3.624;3.628',
 '6;3.627;3.631',
 '7;3.625;3.630',
 '8;3.620;3.623',
 '9;3.610;3.615',
 '10;;',
 '11;;',
 '12;3.615;3.618',
 '13;3.606;3.608',
 '14;3.610;3.615',
 '15;3.610;3.613',
 '16;3.610;3.614',
 '17;;',
 '18;;',
 '19;3.609;3.617',
 '20;3.611;3.615',
 '21;3.612;3.615',
 '22;3.618;3.622',
 '23;;',
 '24;;',
 '25;;',
 '26;;',
 '27;;',
 '28;;',
 '29;;',
 '30;;',
 '31;;']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance!! . It is definitely what i needed. Moreover this approach will help me for other challenging web scraping tasks that i'm facing. Will do additional research on the select method you used at `soup.select('table.calendar-table.table.table-condensed > tbody td[class*="current"]')` #(i don't fully understand what the dots and > are evaluating in that expression but will find out)  since it was the key for solving the problem.

Comment: Happy to help. Find out more about the [css selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)  You do not have to use them, but in my opinion they are more powerful and precise.

Answer (score 0):

`find()` returns `None` when it cannot find the div that you're looking for, and so your code is calling `None.text` which is why Python is complaining that `NoneType` (i.e. the `None` object) has no attribute `text`.

From the [Beautiful Soup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#find(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20**kwargs)), you need to pass the class as a separate argument to `find()`:

```py
bloque.find("div", { "class" : "date" }).text
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However i'm still getting the same error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` . I believe this might be related with the line where i make a partial class name match:
`bloquesdias2 = soup.select('td[class*="table-bordered calendar-day current"]')`
However when i print bloquesdias2.text , it extracts all the data needed, just that it's not in the proper format needed, it is extracting all bulk text from children tags. That's why  i tried to extract each children's tag text and put it in a list, but so far with no success

Comment: If you're getting an error for `NoneType` has no attribute `text` for `bloquesdias2.text` then you shouldn't be able to print `bloquesdias2.text`. The print statement will fail. Your error is probably coming from somewhere else.